# Getting all elements in Selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am very new in Selenium. I have came across a line of code which I can't understand.

```
allElements=sBrowser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//a[@class]")
```

I tried several places the answer I got is, it is finding all the anchor tag in the browser. but what does the

`'.'`

means before

`//a[@class]`

Comment: Your question is really about Xpath rather than Selenium. Here is a good place to start: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath. After you learn the basics, here is a link to a bunch of Xpath functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions.

Comment: `.` means `current node` (`sBrowser`)

Answer (score 1):

```
//y
```

will still find any node, `y`, located anywhere within the XML tree. But, the XPath:

```
.//y
```

will find any node, `y`, that is a descendant of the node `x.` In other words, preceding the `//` expression with a `.` tells the XML search engine to execute the search relative to the current node reference.

Referance: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2142-using-and-expressions-in-xpath-xml-search-directives-in-coldfusion.htm